# How can I connect to Sybase with Perl?

Tags: sql, perl, sybase

I'm trying to a good Perl module to use for connecting to a Sybase database.

My Googling has led me to see `sybperl` as a possible choice, but it hasn't been updated since 2005.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [DBD::Sybase](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD::Sybase) (via DBI). I use this regularly with FreeTDS to connect to SQL Server, but it is actually written against the CT-Lib interface for Sybase.

Answer (score 1):

I found [DBD::Sybase](http://search.cpan.org/~mewp/DBD-Sybase-1.10/Sybase.pm) the best module to use for Sysbase DB and [Sybase::DBlib](http://search.cpan.org/~mewp/sybperl-2.19/DBlib/DBlib.pm) - Sybase DB-Library API.

Comment: if you can give a downvote, please advise what is wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you connect using perl with ODBC to sybase on linux(64 bit)-

Install Sybase Open Client and ODBC driver. (You can get these two from ASE SDK or from ASE server installation)

You need a odbc driver manager, i have tried with unixODBC

Define a driver config like -

```
[Adaptive Server Enterprise]
Description = Sybase ODBC Driver
Driver = /sybase/DataAccess64/ODBC/lib/libsybdrvodb.so
FileUsage = -1
```

Here is a perl sample -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use DBI;
use DBD::ODBC;

BEGIN {
 $ENV{SYBASE}   = "/sybase";
}
my $user = "";
my $passwd = "";
my $server = "";
my $database = "pubs1";
my $port = "5000";
my $data_source = "DBI:ODBC:DRIVER={Adaptive Server Enterprise};server=$server;port=$port;database=$database;";
my @drivers = DBI->available_drivers;
print join(", ", @drivers), "\n";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $user, $passwd)
or die "Can't connect to $data_source: $DBI::errstr";
my $statement = "SELECT * FROM <table_name>";
my @row = $dbh->selectrow_array($statement);
print "@row\n";
$dbh->disconnect;
```

For detailed steps, see - http://kapilraju.tumblr.com/post/131288341356/connect-to-sybase-using-perl-odbc